# Android 2.3 telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName() return empty String

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Android 2.3 telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName() returns an empty String. Is there any other way to get Sim operator name?

Comment: what device are you testing on?

Comment: Hauwei model number is Y210D